# Cannot selecting date on click in the gridview Custom cell

Tags: java, android, gridview, calendar, custom-cell

I'm using `caldroid` with custom cell.

I have a problem when I click the date with description, `onSelectDate` method not running and if I click the date without description, `onSelectDate` method running well.

Please Help me.

Same issue : https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/284

Comment: Please include some code to show what you are doing. It's difficult to say what is wrong from your description.

Comment: </code>final CaldroidListener listener = new CaldroidListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {
                String text = getEventInDate(formatter2.format(date));
                if (text.toString().equals("")) {
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            text,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
};</code>

Comment: you can see screen capture in my link